# Understand Capabilities.APIVersions.Has in helm

Tags: kubernetes-helm, cert-manager, helm3

I have a question about.Capabilities.APIVersions.Has - I am not sure how it works I have the following function:

```
{{- define "fybrik.certManagerApiVersion" -}}
{{- if .Capabilities.APIVersions.Has "cert-manager.io/v1beta1" -}}
cert-manager.io/v1beta1
{{- else if .Capabilities.APIVersions.Has "cert-manager.io/v1alpha2" -}}
cert-manager.io/v1alpha2
{{- else if .Capabilities.APIVersions.Has "certmanager.k8s.io/v1alpha1" -}}
certmanager.k8s.io/v1alpha1
{{- else -}}
cert-manager.io/v1
{{- end -}}
```

kubectl api-versions shows:

```
cert-manager.io/v1
cert-manager.io/v1alpha2
cert-manager.io/v1alpha3
cert-manager.io/v1beta1
```

but I always get cert-manager.io/v1 as the api when the resource is generated using helm install command. I would expect the api would be cert-manager.io/v1beta1 and I wonder what am missing? Thanks

Answer (score 9):

It depends what Helm command are you using.

`helm template` will use apiVersions from kubectl compiled (check here https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/main/go.mod#L43).

`helm install` will use apiVersions available from k8s server, use `helm install --dry-run --debug` to see rendering result.

Comment: It is now also possible to pass api versions to the helm template as well:
`helm template . --api-versions cert-manager.io/v1`

Answer (score 4):

There is a preferred version your cluster will want.

```
$ kubectl get --raw /apis/cert-manager.io | python -m json.tool
{
    "apiVersion": "v1",
    "kind": "APIGroup",
    "name": "cert-manager.io",
    "preferredVersion": {
        "groupVersion": "cert-manager.io/v1",
        "version": "v1"
    },
    "versions": [
        {
            "groupVersion": "cert-manager.io/v1",
            "version": "v1"
        },
        {
            "groupVersion": "cert-manager.io/v1beta1",
            "version": "v1beta1"
        },
        {
            "groupVersion": "cert-manager.io/v1alpha3",
            "version": "v1alpha3"
        },
        {
            "groupVersion": "cert-manager.io/v1alpha2",
            "version": "v1alpha2"
        }
    ]
}
```